# Laravel & LaravelCollective The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Im trying to create DELETE button in my Laravel CRUD app. and have an error:

> (2/2) ErrorException array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

My view:

```
{{!!Form::open(['action' => ['CompanyController@update', $company->id], 'method' => 'PUT'])!!}}
                            {{Form::input('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
                        {{!!Form::close()!!}}
```

I'm using Laravel Collective documentation and it says I can use:

```
 Form::open(['action' => ['Controller@method', $user]])
```

But whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Is `{{!!` valid?  AFAIK, it's either `{{` or `{!!`

Comment: Ye, u'r right. 
{{!! isn't valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide the key. Collective won't try to guess the key name, as we are used to on Laravel.

```
Form::open(['action' => ['Controller@method', $user->id]])
```

The piece of code above shows how to provide the key: **$user->id**

Comment: Uh, how to provide a key with collective?
My variable are working on that view but not in collective...

Comment: Provided code had the answer. Look at $user variable.

Comment: My fault, didn't notice. Thanks